# Converting from Date format to date format in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, data-warehouse

I have a date in a format like `**23-APR-20**` in oracle SQL and I wanna make it 23-04-2020 in date format also not string,how can I handle this please?

Comment: Hint: `to_date()`/`to_char()`. Did you actually search anything before posting?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below type conversion,

```
 select to_date(to_char(date_column, 'DD-MON-YY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY') from table_name;
```

Comment: It gives me the same result **01-APR-20**

Answer (score 0):

This is where you `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` works.

Try this:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-MM-YYYY';
```

Then all your dates will be in dd-mm-yyyy format.

Please note that oracle do not store dates in any format. It stores it in its own binary structure. NLS setting just make the format visible to your client.

Comment: Will this make the NLS_DATE_FORMAT temperament or temporary for this session only?

Comment: Yes, It will alter the NLS parameter for the session only. But You can set it at the database level also. You need to read more about setting NLS parameters